# Add image to Game Object in Unity

Tags: image, pdf, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I have created a whiteboard. I would like to add images and/or pdfs to the whiteboard through a script and be able to change that multiple times. The game object is Mesh that has a Mesh renderer, Mesh Collider, and a white shader. I was actually surprised I could not find this answer anywhere. There is this:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/145185/how-to-add-art-gameobject.html

But this is not through a script and is not setup to be changed multiple times.

If you can give me code which applies to any game object I can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: Are you using normal Images to change that constantly or Sprite Sheet?.

Comment: @RasaMohamed I was going to use normal Images. I am not sure how to use a Sprite Sheet. I will look into I guess

Answer (score 1):

UV map your whiteboard in blender make sure you make a different map for the part of it that you want to assign the dynamic texture to or just make your model from two parts two meshes where the texture changes and where it doesn't then you can assign different textures to it in run time via code like this

```
 public Texture2D tex;
 void change(){
 renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
 }
```

and if you want to keep chaging the texture and all your textures are in one image I mean sprite sheet you can just change the UV`s of your main image to get new textures from your file like this

```
class AnimateSpriteSheet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Columns = 5;
    public int Rows = 5;
    public float FramesPerSecond = 10f;
    public bool RunOnce = true;

    public float RunTimeInSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return ( (1f / FramesPerSecond) * (Columns * Rows) );
        }
    }

    private Material materialCopy = null;

    void Start()
    {
        // Copy its material to itself in order to create an instance not connected to any other
        materialCopy = new Material(renderer.sharedMaterial);
        renderer.sharedMaterial = materialCopy;

        Vector2 size = new Vector2(1f / Columns, 1f / Rows);
        renderer.sharedMaterial.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", size);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(UpdateTiling());
    }

    private IEnumerator UpdateTiling()
    {
        float x = 0f;
        float y = 0f;
        Vector2 offset = Vector2.zero;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = Rows-1; i >= 0; i--) // y
            {
                y = (float) i / Rows;

                for (int j = 0; j <= Columns-1; j++) // x
                {
                    x = (float) j / Columns;

                    offset.Set(x, y);

                    renderer.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", offset);
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / FramesPerSecond);
                }
            }

            if (RunOnce)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code makes run the video texture on objects right ?

Comment: no , for video you should use  movie textures `MovieTexture movie = (MovieTexture)r.material.mainTexture;`

Comment: Okay. But he asked ' through a script and be able to change that constantly ' How it changes constantly and there is no constantly input for Images. Thanks

Comment: @user2320445 I am looking for something like your first solution. How do I turn the image into a texture programmatically